# Пропали навигация и некоторые разделы - на главной странице сайта Drupal

Tags: cms, drupal

Пропало меню на сайте главной страницы сайта Drupal, а также несколько разделов в sidebar, которые тоже отвечают за навигацию.

Вот ссылка http://xn--80aaufhcrwc3dxcwb.xn--p1ai/

Подскажите пожалуйста решить задачу.

Я понимаю, что где-то надо добавить отображение меню на главной странице или возможно решить как-то иначе.

Всем заранее спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Цены настоящие. Прошу прощения, а как это относиться к вопросу?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему. Если кто столкнётся с данной проблемой, то вот решение. Необходим добавить отображение меню, после корректно создать ссылку и правильно назначить главную страницу.
https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/menu-home.html